# How to group or marge SQL rows via PHP after query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a MySQL table like bellow

```
id  |  roll   | exam_id  |  course_id  |  marks  |  status
----------------------------------------------------------
1   |  01001  |     1    |      1      |   56    |    1
2   |  01002  |     1    |      1      |   68    |    1
3   |  01003  |     1    |      1      |   55    |    1
4   |  01004  |     1    |      1      |   67    |    1
5   |  01001  |     1    |      2      |   54    |    1
6   |  01002  |     1    |      2      |   59    |    1
7   |  01003  |     1    |      2      |   62    |    1
8   |  01004  |     1    |      2      |   63    |    1
9   |  01001  |     2    |      3      |   61    |    1
10  |  01002  |     2    |      3      |   48    |    1
11  |  01003  |     2    |      3      |   22    |    1
12  |  01004  |     2    |      3      |   39    |    1
```

Now I want to have all the row with `exam_id = 1`

```
SELECT * FROM result WHERE exam_id=1 ORDER BY course_id
```

After that I need to display this table inside HTML after grouping it by `roll` means one row for each roll that have row-span according to the course number of the result table

```
Roll   |  course_id |  marks
-----------------------------
01001  |      1     |    56
       |      2     |    68
-----------------------------
01002  |      1     |    55
       |      2     |    67
-----------------------------
01003  |      1     |    55
       |      2     |    62
-----------------------------
01004  |      1     |    67
       |      2     |    63
```

I'm using Codeigniter framework to doing this project. Any suggestions about how I can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

**[EDIT]**
Current SQL I'm using to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `exam_result` JOIN `course` ON `course`.`course_tab_id`=`exam_result`.`result_course` WHERE `exam_id` = '1' AND `result_status` = 1 GROUP BY `exam_result`.`exam_roll`, `course`.`course_tab_id` ORDER BY `exam_result`.`exam_roll` ASC, `course`.`course_id` ASC
```

Comment: Why don't you group it by roll in SQL query itself and just use that data to bind to your HTML table or whatever you are using for display in UI

Comment: use `array_merge`.

Comment: Just order by roll and course_id ```SELECT * FROM result WHERE exam_id=1 ORDER BY roll, course_id```

Comment: Fetch data with `GROUP BY roll, course_id ` and do a loop and create an `array` with `roll` as index and store the rest in it.

Comment: Group it by roll and the course_id then order it by roll, course_id or marks

Comment: I've edited my question. You can see my current SQL query. Please have a look and suggest me what can I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this but the difference in this table on my first query is that the course title will be included on a single table, I have set the marks as AVG due to so if ever you have duplicate data you will see their average result for the course and roll of a school or whatever you use this structure for

```
SELECT roll, exam_id, a.course_id, marks, status, course_title, course_credit
FROM
(SELECT roll, exam_id, course_id, AVE(marks) as marks, status FROM result) as a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT course_id, course_title, course_credit FROM course) as b
ON
a.course_id = b.course_id
WHERE exam_id = '1' -- you can remove this if you wanted all exam appear on your list
GROUP BY roll, exam_id, a.course_id, marks, status, course_title, course_credit
ORDER BY roll, course_id, marks
```

Comment: Though this not solve my problem, but I got a solution from this answer. So thank you :)

Comment: What is your answer that you have found ^^_ can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query

```
SELECT Roll, course_id, AVG(marks) 
FROM result WHERE exam='1' 
GROUP BY Roll, course_id 
ORDER BY roll, course_id, marks
```

Comment: This is my current SQL query. `SELECT * FROM `exam_result` JOIN `course` ON `course`.`course_tab_id`=`exam_result`.`result_course` WHERE `exam_id` = '1' AND `result_status` = 1 GROUP BY `exam_result`.`exam_roll`, `course`.`course_tab_id` ORDER BY `exam_result`.`exam_roll` ASC, `course`.`course_id` ASC
`

Comment: how many table do you have, why do you use JOIN if you only have one table. can you show the structure of your table.

Comment: Actually I have 2 joined tables. I have posted only the simplified structure of my problem.

Comment: What is the structure of both table so I can have an answer to your question, I thought you only have one and you just wanted to arrange it in your given order.

Comment: Other table is `course` that contains only `course_id`, `course_title`, `course_credit`

Comment: SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM result) as a
LEFT JOIN